# How should I pass Dependencies to my Class?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, sonarqube, autofac

I have a class that relies on a lot of dependencies which are injected via Autofac.
This is an example:

```
public MyService(
        IService1 service1,
        IService2 service2,
        ...)
        {
          _service1 = service1;
          _service2 = service2
        }
```

there are approx 10 dependencies I need to pass. We now implemented SonarQube that complaints about a lot of Constructor parameters.

Is there another "better/preferred" way to pass those dependencies to make SonarQube happy?

Comment: bundle them together into a class `DependencyPackage` and you have only 1 parameter. SonarQube will propbably be much happier ;)

Comment: @Mong that's just shifting the blame. Now `DependencyPackage`'s constructor will have the same amount of parameters...

Comment: That would mean I either pass the params to that class which results into the same problem or I set properties at the time i instantiate which requires access to the DI container to resolve the dependencies right? The class that actually instantiates the MyService has no access to the Container of Autfac.

Comment: You could also mark this class as an exception in Sonarqube that this rule should not apply here.

Comment: If a class has 10 dependencies, it's probably doing too much and therefore hard to maintain and test, and that's exactly what SonarQube is trying to tell you. You need to refactor it to get rid of this warning.

Comment: Are you actually having issues due to the amount of dependencies? Code analysis should be a tool to help highlight code that is problematic for one reason or another. So the question should be how to make *you* happy, not SonarQube.

Comment: @CodeCaster " that's just shifting the blame. ", "If a class has 10 dependencies, it's probably doing too much and therefore hard to maintain and test, " true words! thanx for the reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's always good to review your dependency layout to make sure your 'tree' of dependencies is as simple as possible, sometimes you just need to pass in a fairly large number of dependencies.

To help simplify this, you could consider the [Aggregate Services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/aggregate-services.html) package.

It will allow you to define an interface with your dependencies in it, and then inject that interface, without defining a whole other class yourself.

Comment: This sounds good and seem to solve my problem for now until we do a full refactoring